# How to connect rows in sql with same value but in different columns in the same table?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to merge data with same value from different columns and only stop showing records that no connected value. For example I have:

```
ID                TaxDecNo              PrevTaxDec
1                 5374                  11135
2                 9864                  7394
3                 11135                 21784
4                 7394                  6872
5                 21784                 N/A
6                 6872                  N/A
```

I would like to display like this.
When I select ID 3

```
ID                TaxDecNo              PrevTaxDec
1                 5374                  11135
3                 11135                 21784
5                 21784                 N/A
```

When I select ID 2

```
ID                TaxDecNo              PrevTaxDec
2                 9864                  7394
4                 7394                  6872
6                 6872                  N/A
```

Please help me how to query using sqlserver.

Comment: This is effectively a hierarchy but you want to "traverse" in both directions. You would need to use an rCTE to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you'll need an rCTE (recursive Common Table Expressions) here. As you want to "traverse" both up and down the hierarchy you'll need 2 rCTEs, for the "up" and "down". Afterwards you then need to `UNION` the 2 datasets from the expressions:

```
DECLARE @ID int = 3;

WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT V.ID,
           V.TaxDecNo,
           V.PrevTaxDec
    FROM (VALUES(1,5374,11135),
                (2,9864,7394),
                (3,11135,21784),
                (4,7394,6872),
                (5,21784,NULL), --I assume you aren't really mixing datatyoes. 'N/A' can't be inserted into an int column
                (6,6872,NULL))V(ID,TaxDecNo,PrevTaxDec)),
--Solution
rCTEup AS(
    SELECT YT.ID,
           YT.TaxDecNo,
           YT.PrevTaxDec
    FROM YourTable YT
    WHERE YT.ID = @ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT YT.ID,
           YT.TaxDecNo,
           YT.PrevTaxDec
    FROM rCTEup r
         JOIN YourTable YT ON r.TaxDecNo = YT.PrevTaxDec),
rCTEdown AS(
    SELECT YT.ID,
           YT.TaxDecNo,
           YT.PrevTaxDec
    FROM YourTable YT
    WHERE YT.ID = @ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT YT.ID,
           YT.TaxDecNo,
           YT.PrevTaxDec
    FROM rCTEdown r
         JOIN YourTable YT ON r.PrevTaxDec = YT.TaxDecNo)
SELECT ID,
       TaxDecNo,
       PrevTaxDec
FROM rCTEup
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,
       TaxDecNo,
       PrevTaxDec
FROM rCTEdown
WHERE ID != @ID; --As it'll be in rCTEup
```

Comment: how about if it is in the same table? thank you for your response

Comment: The above does reference one table, @ClydeLesterSevilla , `YourTable`. Not sure what your point is.

Comment: You're welcome @ClydeLesterSevilla . Please do considering accepted the answer as the solution if so. Future readers then know the answer was helpful. You also get reputation for accepting an answer; which is really important for getting those early privileges.

Comment: how about create a procedure assume that i already added data in the table and please add this column 'OwnerName'

Comment: If you're changing the goal posts, @ClydeLesterSevilla, you should be asking a new question. Especially when those goal posts are anywhere near the question you asked.

Comment: Aren't anywhere near*

Comment: Pls help me @Larnu on how to convert in to stored procedure which the given value is already in the table and no more declared value. I cant finish my thesis because of this pls help me!

Comment: You were also shown how to create an SP in your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60437629/part-2-how-to-create-stored-procedure-with-connected-rows-in-sql-with-same-valu)