# Part 2: How to create stored procedure with connected rows in sql with same value but in different columns in one table?

Tags: sql-server

I already asked question about on how to display and merge data with same value from different columns and only stop showing records that no connected value. My problem is i dont know how it works using stored procedure. For example assume that I already added this data in the database:

```
ID  |  TaxDecNo  |  OwnerName  |   PrevTaxDec
----------------------------------------------
1   |  5374      |  John       |   11135
2   |  9864      |  Doe        |   7394
3   |  11135     |  John       |   21784
4   |  7394      |  Doe        |   6872
5   |  21784     |  John       |   NULL
6   |  6872      |  Doe        |   NULL
```

I would like to display like this. When I select ID 3

```
ID  |  TaxDecNo  |  OwnerName  |   PrevTaxDec
----------------------------------------------
1   |  5374      |  John       |   11135
3   |  11135     |  John       |   21784
5   |  21784     |  John       |   NULL
```

When I select ID 2

```
ID  |  TaxDecNo  |  OwnerName  |   PrevTaxDec
----------------------------------------------
2   |  9864      |  Doe        |   7394
4   |  7394      |  Doe        |   6872
6   |  6872      |  Doe        |   NULL
```

- Please help me on how to create stored procedure using sqlserver. Thank You!

Comment: if you already had a question, you should edit it or precisely tell us your problem.

Comment: and with connected order

Comment: Where is your attempt so far?

Comment: @DanielA.White I asked the OP to ask a new question, as stored procedures have nothing to do with the qusetion they asked before. They got the answer they original asked, and now they have a follow on question. Editting the old question invalidates nay effort from other users, including myself.

Comment: Related [How to connect rows in sql with same value but in different columns in the same table?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60412329/2029983)

Comment: @Larnu fair enough. this question is hard to follow without the other one however. specifics are needed.

Comment: I appreciate having a new question but this effort lacks enough detail for anybody to follow this.

Comment: What part(s) do you need help with? How to write the query or how to create a procedure? It isn't clear what you want here.

Comment: I agree, the OP should include the information from the prior question that is related, and cite the changes they made to the prior answer they failed to apply. This doesn't expand on the prior question at all

Comment: @Larnu I think they may be asking how to take your answer and move that into a stored procedure.

Comment: You're *probably* right, @SeanLange , which makes it really confusing, as they've not even shown the solution from the previous question at all.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Stored Procedure which takes the ID as a parameter

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure] 
@ID int

AS
BEGIN

-- All the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/60412515/1818795
-- except the DECLARE statement

END
GO
```