# How to select specific rows using datagridview and display in new form using datagridview but with the stored procedure apply

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have 2 Forms form1 and form2. Form1 displays all the data record while Form2 filter data records.

I have a stored procedure given from [How to connect rows in sql with same value but in different columns in the same table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60412329/how-to-connect-rows-in-sql-with-same-value-but-in-different-columns-in-the-same/60412515#60412515)

What I wanted is how to select specific rows from form1 and display it in form2 using a string ID so that I can easily call ID from form1 and merge it to Form2 ID stored procedure.

Thank you all!

Comment: You need to connect the forms by the instance.  See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, you want to show specific rows in form2 from form1.

I viewed the stored procedure from another link, however, I find that I could not use that stored procedure.

Therefore, I created the following stored procedure which may satisfied with your requirement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestProcedure]
 @ID int
 AS
if(@ID%2=0)
Begin
select * from Product where ID%2=0
End
Else
Begin
select * from Product where ID%2!=0
End
```

Then, I used the following code to call the stored procedure successfully.

Code:

Form1:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public TextBox textBox
        {
            get
            {
                return textBox1;
            }
            set
            {
                textBox1 = value;
            }

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Connstring = @"connectstring";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Connstring);
            string sql = "select * from Product";
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
            DataSet set = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(set);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = set.Tables[0];
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            form2.ShowDialog();


        }
    }
```

Form2:

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 form =(Form1) Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
            string Connstring = @"connectionstring";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Connstring);
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("TestProcedure", connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(form.textBox.Text));
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            var commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
            var ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]